# How to remove navigation controls from Firefox right click menu?

Tags: firefox, context-menu

A recent firefox update has changed the context menu when you right click on a page to display icons such as back, forward, stop and bookmark:

[image]

Is there any way to remove them?

I'm using Firefox 32 on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: What version exactly?  Without this information in 2 years this question won't be helpful.

Comment: Added version info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no built-in method of doing it. However you can use one of the addons. Try using [Menu Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/). The name of the tool is pretty self explanatory. Does what it says - allows you to edit context menu.

[image]

Comment: I could not find these controls in the item list but just clicking Apply without making any changes somehow removed them from the context menu. :D

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Classic Theme Restorer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) to replace the context menu icons with labels:

[image: context menu text]

Answer (score 2):

Add to Stylish:

```
#context-navigation,
#context-sep-navigation {
  display:none !important;
}
```

source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2865005